# Can I pass MapstateToProps without any arguments?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to have a `mapStateToProps` argument (to redux `connect` binding) only if the part of the state I am looking for is available, return `null` otherwise. But I feel this is redundant since `mapSateToProps`'s first argument itself is the state...

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import store from '~/store'

import MyForm from '~/MyForm'

const formdata = store.getSate().form.myReduxForm.values

const mapStateToProps = formData ? ({ form }) => ({
  formData: form.myReduxForm.values,
}) : null

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyForm)
```

can I do it like this since I already have the states slice I need

```
mapStateToProps = formData ? () => ({
  formData: formdata 
}) : null
```

Comment: Why are getting the state directly from the store instead of using mapStateToProps? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: If there's nothing to connect, you could pass `null` instead of `mapStateToProps`. Connect doesn't have to have both its arguments. But like Ori said, not too sure why you're directly accessing the store, and you should probably do the connecting of the component within the component file itself.

Comment: I agree with both Ori Drori and Jayce444 you should consider doing either mapStateToProps or directly access the store via props.store.getState(). No need to do both. :)

Comment: I edited the question it was wrong

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where are you taking `manualFormData`.

You could do in your `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ form }) => {
  if (!manualFormData) { return {} }

  return {
    formData: form.BanksNewManual.values,
  }
```

}